# Ember tranistionToRoute error

Tags: ember.js

From a controller action "submit" I am getting this error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at String.indexOf (native)
at get (http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember.prod.js:16123:41)
at ControllerMixin.reopen.transitionToRoute (http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember.prod.js:19948:22)
at ControllerMixin.reopen.transitionToRoute (http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember.prod.js:19950:23)
```

here is the offending code:

```
 actions: {
    submit: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.get('model').save().then(function() {
             self.transitionToRoute('animals');
        });
    }
}
```

Now, #/animals works when typed in the URL. And I have tried the variations:

```
self.transitionToRoute('animals.index');

and
self.transitionToRoute('/animals');
```

And none of them work. What is the problem?

Comment: that code is totally cool (except the variations), you've got some code somewhere else that's an issue (a recursive computed property or something), can you show your animals route and controller, and maybe router.

Comment: I see what the problem is. I have controllerName  set to animalDetails because I want several routes to use this controller. However, the controller is created with it's target as the controller, the controller doesn't have the router as it's target. I have no idea how to fix it. I tried changing this to a Mixin and I get other errors. Is there anyway to leave it like I have it and get the router back as the target?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out. Setting controllerName in the route to something other than the default controller left my controller without a target of the apps router. The code for transitionToRouter calls the controllers target, which it expects to be the apps router. In my case the controller target points to itself. So next I tried a mixin and got the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null

Which looks like it is related to this:

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/dynamically-extending-object-instances-with-mixin/5411/5

Basically I can't use my mixin cause it has properties that have meta data. So I guess I am stuck copying and pasting.